Help me find a correlation between Fourier series and transform
For the Fourier series in bounded domains, we use that the Laplacian is compact self adjoint operator. By spectral theory it’s eigen unction form a basis, so the Fourier series makes perfect sens. Just as in finite dimension for a vector (function) $v∈L^2 (Ω)$ you find the vector projection along the basis vectors:
(1) $∫_Ωv e_n dx=c_n$
And then decompose the vector just as in finite dimension
(2) $v=∑_{n=1}^∞c_n e_n$
This to me makes perfect sense.
On the other hand, the Fourier transform was introduced separately, and it had nothing to do with the Fourier series. I was introduced to Fourier series by slowly constructing it on $L^1 (R^n)$ then extended to $L^2 (R^n)$, finding it’s inverse and so on. However, the formulas are extremely similar, namely:
(3) $v ̂(ζ)=∫_Ωv e^{-2πiζx} dx$
(4) $v(x)=∫_Ωv ̂  e^{2πiζx} dx$
So as I see it 1 and 3 give the “projection” of v along another vector, however the similarities stop there. For example:

If I try to compare (2) and (4) I see that (2) is just the normal vector decomposition while (4) is not, $v ̂ (ζ)$ at any $ζ$ is the projection of $v$ to $e^ {-2πiζx}$, but when reconstructing the vector we have to use v ̂$e^{2πiζx}$. I have seen the computation and I’m ok with them, but I just find the difference weird

in cases (3) and (4) we can't even talk about “projections” since $e^{-2πiζx}∉L^2 (R^n )$


So as I see it, it’s really just some “luck” that the Fourier series is similar to the transformation, and in fact it is lucky that the Fourier series can be defined at all. So I was wondering there some theory that unifies the 2 in a more general case? Something like:
The operator $L$ is compact self adjoint in bounded domains $Ω$ as such it forms a basis whit its eigenvectors ${e_n |n∈N}$. And in the case $Ω=R^n$ if it has a continuous spectrum we can replace the series with an integral?
